# Rails or Django style routing in Perl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, django, perl, routes, url-routing

I have grown accustomed to the way Rails maps a route or the Django uses regex on a route (I am not expect in Django, but this is what I have heard how it does it's routing) and how they use the style of permalinks to access a particle web page. Is it possible to do the same thing in Perl?

Comment: Sure it's possible. Perhaps you are asking how to do it with a particular Perl framework though?

Comment: You might be interested with http://www.catalystframework.org/

Comment: Is it possible without a framework?

Comment: Rails and Django are frameworks as well. I'd be a bit irritated if a general purpose language contained this functionality in its core (core language, not core libs).

Comment: @phaylon Yes I know Rails and Django are frameworks, but I don't want to use a framework. I just want a module without the requirement of all these other fuss that tends to come with framework like having to build an application and fit in with a specific framework.

Comment: Here's [some modules](http://showmetheco.de/articles/2011/3/perl-routes-dispatching-comparison.html) to facilitate outside of a framework

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the Perl web framework with most Rails-like routing would be [`Mojolicious`](http://mojolicious.org/)

The creator of [`Mojolicious`](http://mojolicious.org/) did write an excellent blog post called "Dispatchers for dummies" comparing the major Perl, Ruby & Python web frameworks and highlighting what he believed were improvements he made with routing on [`Mojolicious`](http://mojolicious.org/).

Unfortunately above post is no longer online :(   Instead you have to settle for the [`Mojolicious::Guides::Routing`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Mojolicious/lib/Mojolicious/Guides/Routing.pod) documentation.  Here is a routing example from the docs:

```
package MyApp;
use base 'Mojolicious';

sub startup {
    my $self = shift;

    # Router
    my $r = $self->routes;

    # Route
    $r->route('/welcome')->to(controller => 'foo', action => 'welcome');
}

1;
```

There are also other Perl frameworks which provide direct URL to action routing:

- [`Jifty`](http://jifty.org)   (uses a nice [routing DSL](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Jifty/lib/Jifty/Dispatcher.pm))
- [`Dancer`](http://perldancer.org/) (Ruby [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/)-like)
- [`Mojolicious::Lite`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Mojolicious/lib/Mojolicious/Lite.pm) (ditto)
- [`Squatting`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Squatting/) (inspired by Ruby [Camping](http://www.ruby-camping.com/))
- [`Web::Simple`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Web-Simple/lib/Web/Simple.pm)

A more complete list of [Perl web frameworks](http://www.perlfoundation.org/perl5/index.cgi?web_frameworks) can be found on the [Perl5 wiki](http://www.perlfoundation.org/perl5/)

And if you are framework adverse then take a look at [`Plack`](http://plackperl.org/) (<sup><sub>also see [PSGI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PSGI) wikipedia)</sub></sup>.  This is same as [Rack](http://rack.rubyforge.org/) on Ruby and [WSGI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Server_Gateway_Interface) on Python.

Here is a quick and dirty example of Plack:

```
use 5.012;
use warnings;

my $app = sub {
    my $env = shift;

    given ($env->{PATH_INFO}) {

        return [ 200, [ 'Content-Type' => 'text/plain' ], [ 'Hello Baz!' ] ]
            when '/hello/baz';

        default {
            return [ 200, [ 'Content-Type' => 'text/plain' ], [ 'Hello World' ]];
        }
    }
}
```

Then use `plackup above_script.psgi` and away you go.

Comment: Mojolicious::Lite might be easier to get started with than full-blown Mojolicious .. http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Mojolicious::Lite

Answer (score 3):

[Quite possible](http://www.catalystframework.org/calendar/2008/11) with [Catalyst](http://catalystframework.org), although nobody ever seems to use it, except for internationalising the internally defined dispatch paths.